# How to get Catch weight concept in Ax 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

Is there Catch Weight concept in Axapta 2009 as it is in Axapta 2012 ?
If not how to achieve same in AX 2009. Is there any work around ?

Please Help :)

Comment: No it is a new functionality in Ax 2012.  You can realize it in Ax 2009, but I think it is a big enough modification.

Comment: Is it possible from Barcode masking or if I create more than one UOM for same item ?

Comment: You need track Qty of item for each inventory transaction in two units of measure.

Comment: Any other way to do it other than UOM

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Implement the feature yourself (maybe limited functionality)
2. Upgrade to AX 2012

Both will take time and effort.